# NGXS @Selector() trigers from other state. But, why?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

Hi I have several state classes and I have a problem, that one of my selectors triggers in unobvious moment.

app.module.ts

```
NgxsModule.forRoot([...stateList],
        {
            selectorOptions: {
                injectContainerState: true,
                suppressErrors: true
            }
        }),
```

chart.state.ts

```
@Selector()
static getIsEmptyArchive(state: ChartStateModel): ChartErrorTypeInterface {
    console.trace();
    console.log(state.isEmptyArchive);
    return state.isEmptyArchive;
}
```

I check all triggers of this selector. Once, I get stranger console.trace()and  then I see trigger from another state

> (anonymous) @   groups.state.ts:279

[image]

But my selector doesn't have some connect with groups.state.ts. And selector gives default value in this moment.

groups.state.ts: 279

```
            ctx.setState({
            ...state,
            groups: result.data,
            isGroupsLoaded: true,
        });
```

I don't understand, why my selector is triggered from other state